Fixing shed flooring
I installed pressure-treated plywood subflooring in my shed, but I made the mistake of not placing the edges along the floor joists so now I have some warping and bounce. Since I have built the rest of the shed and would like a nice flat floor, I was going to install a second layer of premium, OSB tongue and groove subfloor. I’m wondering if that is a good idea and if so, should I install the OSB in a different direction than the existing subfloor (I.e. perpendicular?) This second layer of subfloor would have 3 inch screws that go directly into the floor joists, and I would put some adhesive in the tongue and grooves.

I would not use OSB. I would go with plywood. Since the edges of the first layer of plywood flex, any weight on the OSB above that area will result in the OSB breaking over time.  If the OSB gets wet it turns into oatmeal as well.

Would you try to align edges of the second layer of plywood with the joists and screw down through both layers? Or would you just screw directly into the first layer of plywood? Would you use adhesive?

I would rip up the ply wood not installed properly, but let's assume that I am asked to do this for someone that wants it left down.   Top plywood gets aligned with joists.  Yes some liquid nails is also used.  Definitely screw down through both layers and into joists.
